# How could database have worse benchmark results on faster disk?

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, amazon-ec2, benchmarking

I'm benchmarking comparable (2vCPU, 2G RAM) server (Ubuntu 18.04) from DigitalOcean (DO) and AWS EC2 (t3a.small).

The disk benchmark (fio) goes inline with the results of https://dzone.com/articles/iops-benchmarking-disk-io-aws-vs-digitalocean

In summary:

DO --

READ: bw=218MiB/s (229MB/s), 218MiB/s-218MiB/s (229MB/s-229MB/s), io=3070MiB (3219MB), run=14060-14060msec

WRITE: bw=72.0MiB/s (76.5MB/s), 72.0MiB/s-72.0MiB/s (76.5MB/s-76.5MB/s), io=1026MiB (1076MB), run=14060-14060msec

EC2 --

READ: bw=9015KiB/s (9232kB/s), 9015KiB/s-9015KiB/s (9232kB/s-9232kB/s), io=3070MiB (3219MB), run=348703-348703msec

WRITE: bw=3013KiB/s (3085kB/s), 3013KiB/s-3013KiB/s (3085kB/s-3085kB/s), io=1026MiB (1076MB), run=348703-348703msec

which shows DO disk more than 10 times faster than the EBS of EC2

However, sysbench following https://severalnines.com/database-blog/how-benchmark-postgresql-performance-using-sysbench is showing DO *slower* than EC2 (using Postgres 11 default configuration, read-write test on oltp_legacy/oltp.lua )

DO --

transactions: 14704 (243.87 per sec.)

Latency (ms):

min: 9.06

avg: 261.77

max: 2114.04

95th percentile: 383.33

EC2 --

transactions: 20298 (336.91 per sec.)

Latency (ms):

min: 5.85

avg: 189.47

max: 961.27

95th percentile: 215.44

What could be the explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequential read/write throughput matters for large sequential scans, stuff like data warehousing, loading a large backup, etc.

Your benchmark is OLTP which does lots of small quick queries. For this sequential throughput is irrelevant.

For reads (SELECTs) the most important factor is having enough RAM to keep your working set in cache and not do any actual IO. Failing that, it is read random access time.

For writes (UPDATE,INSERT) then the fsync latency, which is the time required to commit data to stable storage, is the most important factor since the database will only finish a COMMIT when data has been written.

Most likely the EC2 has better random access and fsync performance. Maybe it uses SSDs or battery-backed cache.

Answer (score 0):

Sequential bandwidth and latency / iops are independent parameters.

Some workloads (like DBs) depend on latency for lots of small IOs.  Or throughput for lots of small IO operations, iops (IOs per second).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to IOPS vs throughput which others mentioned. I also wanted to point out that they are both pretty similar numbers. 240 tps vs 330 tps. you could add or subtract almost that much by just doing things like vacuum, analyze, or let it sit there for a while.

there could be other factors too. CPU speed could be different, there could be one performance for short burst vs throttling a heavy user, there could be presence or absence of huge_pages, different cache timings, memory speeds, or different nvme drivers. the point is 240 is not as much less than 330 as you might think.

Update: something else to point out is that OLTP read/write transactions arent necessary bottlenecked by disk performance. if you have sync off, then it really isnt.
I dont know exactly what the sysbench legacy OLTP read write test is doing, but I suspect its more like a bank xaction touching multiple records, using indexes, ... its probably not some sort of raw max insertion rate, or MAX CRUD operation rate benchmark.

I get 1000 tps on my desktop in the write heavy benchmark against pg13, but i can insert something like 50k records per second, each being ~ 100 bytes records from just a single process python client during bulk loads. and nearly 100k w/ sync off.

Comment: "240 tps vs 330 tps" -- Where do those numbers come from?

Comment: they are your numbers. the xactions per second number inside parenthesis